# DSquery on AD share leaking company infomation

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, exploit, vulnerability

Today i found DSquery on one of my smb shares at work. I ran it to query users and since my company uses IC numbers as the unique CN, i got to see all my colleagues ICs which is a breach of personal information already.

Firstly, is this considered a vulnerability? and secondly how can this be mitigated from the another [question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/109788/restrict-users-from-running-dsquery-and-dsget?newreg=ca59f1b5addb441e828d1a1c6c87ecf9) there seems to be no sure way to harden the AD in this manner to mitigate against such attacks.

Attacker will just need any user acct and since this is a smb share on the AD SYSVOL, any windows box connected to the domain can be used to exploit this.

Answer (score 4):

> since my company uses IC numbers as the unique CN, i got to see all my colleagues ICs which is a breach of personal information already.

Perhaps you shouldn't use the IC number then.

> Firstly, is this considered a vulnerability?

If it is it's a self-inflicted vulnerability, since Windows doesn't do this on it's own. You've kind of created your own problem here.

> Attacker will just need any user acct and since this is a smb share on the AD SYSVOL, any windows box connected to the domain can be used to exploit this.

Yes, as would be the case for any and all data and information in the domain if someone were to successfully gain unauthorized access to your domain.